# Get this error during update ember 3.28 and How can solve it?

Tags: ember-cli

WARNING: [DEPRECATION] [DEPRECATION] Usage of the Ember Global is deprecated. You should import the Ember module or the specific API instead.

See https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x/#toc_ember-global for details.

Usages of the Ember Global may be caused by an outdated ember-cli-babel dependency. The following steps may help:

If using yarn, run npx yarn-deduplicate --packages ember-cli-babel followed by yarn install.
If using npm, run npm dedupe.
Upgrade the following addons to the latest version:
ember-cli-addon-docs
ember-qunit
Important
In order to avoid repeatedly showing the same deprecation messages, no further deprecation messages will be shown for usages of the Ember Global until ember-cli-babel is upgraded to v7.26.6 or above.

To see all instances of this deprecation message, set the EMBER_GLOBAL_DEPRECATIONS environment variable to "all", e.g. EMBER_GLOBAL_DEPRECATIONS=all ember test.

Details
Prior to v7.26.6, ember-cli-babel sometimes transpiled imports into the equivalent Ember Global API, potentially triggering this deprecation message indirectly, even when you did not observe these deprecated usages in your code.

The following outdated versions are found in your project:

ember-cli-babel@6.18.0, currently used by:
@ember/ordered-set@2.0.3
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.16.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0 > @ember-data/record-data@3.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill@2.0.2 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.17.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-assign-polyfill@2.6.0 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.16.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-svg-jar@2.2.3
Added by ember-qunit@4.6.0 > @ember/test-helpers@1.7.1
ember-auto-import@1.5.3 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
Added by @zoho/ember-product-tour@1.0.1
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-cli-deploy-zf-build@1.12.2 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
ember-cli-test-loader@2.2.0 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.8.1
Added by ember-qunit@4.6.0
ember-fetch-adapter@0.4.3
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.12.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-fetch@6.7.2
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.8.2
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-get-config@0.2.4
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.3.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-href-to@1.15.1
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.8.2
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-ignore-children-helper@1.0.1
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.8.2
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-modal-dialog@3.0.0-beta.4
ember-inflector@3.0.1
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
ember-keyboard@4.0.0
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-maybe-import-regenerator@0.1.6 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.0.0-beta.4
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-concurrency@1.1.7
ember-named-arguments-polyfill@1.0.0 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-router-service-polyfill@1.0.3 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.8.2
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-href-to@1.15.1
ember-tether@1.0.0
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-truth-helpers@2.1.0
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.6.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-wormhole@0.5.5
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^6.10.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-modal-dialog@3.0.0-beta.4
ember-cli-babel@7.19.0, currently used by:
@ember-data/adapter@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember-data/canary-features@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0 > @ember-data/model@3.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0 > @ember-data/private-build-infra@3.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0 > @ember-data/record-data@3.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0 > @ember-data/store@3.18.0
@ember-data/debug@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember-data/model@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember-data/private-build-infra@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember-data/record-data@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember-data/serializer@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember-data/store@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-data@3.18.0
@ember/test-helpers@1.7.1 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-qunit@4.6.0
@glimmer/component@1.1.2 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
ember-app-scheduler@1.0.8 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.1.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-router-scroll@1.3.3
ember-cli-addon-docs-yuidoc@0.2.4 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
ember-cli-clipboard@0.13.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-cli-postcss@5.0.0 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.1.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-cli-string-helpers@4.0.6 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-code-snippet@3.0.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-component-css@0.7.4 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.1.4
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-composable-helpers@2.4.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.1.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-concurrency@1.1.7 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-data@3.18.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.18.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-load-initializers@2.1.1 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.11.0
ember-modal-dialog@3.0.0-beta.4 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.1.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-modifier-manager-polyfill@1.2.0 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.10.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0 > ember-on-modifier@1.0.1
ember-on-modifier@1.0.1 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.19.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-qunit@4.6.0 (Dormant)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.12.0
ember-resolver@7.0.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.13.2
ember-responsive@3.0.6 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.19.0
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-router-scroll@1.3.3 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.1.2
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-svg-jar@2.2.3 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
ember-test-waiters@1.2.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.11.0
Added by ember-qunit@4.6.0 > @ember/test-helpers@1.7.1
liquid-fire@0.31.0 (Compatible)
Depends on ember-cli-babel@^7.7.3
Added by ember-cli-addon-docs@0.7.0
Note: Addons marked as "Dormant" does not appear to have any JavaScript files. Therefore, even if they are using an old version ember-cli-babel, they are unlikely to be the culprit of this deprecation and can likely be ignored.

Note: Addons marked as "Compatible" are already compatible with ember-cli-babel@7.26.6. If using yarn, try running npx yarn-deduplicate --packages ember-cli-babel followed by yarn install.If using npm, try running npm dedupe.

during update ember 3.28 how can solve it?